# How to find a positive or negative value inside a string?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a Problem with a little program in Python 3.3, which should return a number from a string.

While it works well for positive values,

```
text = "XXXXXXX\nDateMinEnd=230\nXXXXXXX\n"
Dmin = re.search('(?<=DateMinEnd=)\w+',text)
Dmin_res = int(Dmin.group())
print(Dmin_res)
230
```

there is "None" result for negative values:

```
text = "XXXXXXX\nDateMinEnd=-230\nXXXXXXX\n"
Dmin = re.search('(?<=DateMinEnd=)\w+',text)
Dmin_res = int(Dmin.group())

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I am really a beginner, so I would appreciate any hints (and of course I had a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html before asking you and tried raw string and several special escapes, but unfortunately I am not able find the solution). Thanking you in advance.

Andreas

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters here, but make sure to look at the python 3 documentation, as some things have changed: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html

Comment: Thank you all for your extremly fast and valuable answers! Thank you @Ilmo Euro for the digit hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding an optional minus sign in the regular expression:

```
Dmin = re.search('(?<=DateMinEnd=)-?\w+', text)
```

`-` is the minus sign itself, and `?` marks that there may be one or zero minus symbols (in other words it's optional).

Answer (score 6):

If you only need support for integers, you can add an optional `-` in front of your `\w`:

```
Dmin = re.search('(?<=DateMinEnd=)-?\w+',text)
```

Also, `\w` matches also non-digits, so you may want to use `\d` (for *digit*) instead:

```
Dmin = re.search('(?<=DateMinEnd=)-?\d+',text)
```

**EDIT**

If you need support for non-integers, use the following regex:

```
Dmin = re.search('(?<=DateMinEnd=)-?\d*\.?\d+',text)
```

Let's break it down:

```
-?  # optional negation
\d* # zero or more digits
\.? # optional decimal point (. is special so we need to escape it)
\d+ # one or more digits
```

Answer (score 1):

`-` isn't captured by `\w`. I would just do something like this:

```
Dmin = re.search('DateMinEnd=(.*)', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

`-` is not a word(`\w+`)

to search all types,  replace `\w+` with `.+`

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the regular expression that the `-` sign is optional, and if it exists, capture it.

So your expression should be `('(?<=DateMinEnd=)(-?\d+)'`

I changed `\w+` to `\d+` since you are looking for numbers, not words. The `-?` makes the `-` optional, and the `( )` surrounding the expression make it into a capture group.

So now you get:

```
>>> re.search('(?<=DateMinEnd=)(-?\d+)', text).group()
'-230'
```